# How can relatively low-level characters get an idea of what's behind the door?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

When exploring a dungeon, we rarely hear anything when we listen at doors (even with a very high listen check result). We have walked in on some strong but silent types without warning. As a party I feel like we don't have enough player experience to know useful strategies. Our DM is also inexperienced, so there's mentorship in strategy to be found there.

What are good ways for relatively low-level characters (say levels 4-8) to get some idea of what is behind the next door, in order to figure out when it would be a good idea to use buffing spells?

For what it's worth, the party does not include an arcane caster, but does have a psion and a favored soul, as well as a scout-type character.

Trying a listen check at the door is standard, but what else might they try if the listen check fails to reveal anything (as often seems to be the case)?  And even when something is heard, it's not necessarily helpful in terms of knowing "how dangerous" the thing we hear shuffling around inside the room is.

Casting augury outside every door seems a bit extreme.... but beats "wasting" multiple buffs outside every door "just in case" when many of them wear off pretty quickly.

In terms of resources, the party could probably pool together up to 10k gp for something, depending on how helpful it would be. But we have some basic needs as well (better AC, better weapon, better saving throws...), so expense *is* an object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try knocking.

Seriously though, there's some good low-level options. The first one that comes to mind is [Detect Evil](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectEvil.htm). It's a first level cleric spell (which means your favored soul should be able to cast it), it emanates in a 60 foot cone, and does exactly what it says on the tin. Plus:

> The spell can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks it.

Unless you're facing some paranoid villains, this should give you some information on who's hiding on the other side of the door. If you run up on a sheet of lead that blocks your detect spell, that should probably tell you something too.

[Detect Thoughts](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectThoughts.htm) is even better, but I'm not sure if anyone in your party can cast it (although the Psion might, depending on the build.) This one is great because within one round, you get to detect:

> Presence or absence of thoughts (from conscious creatures with Intelligence scores of 1 or higher).

So you're not limited by alignment. There are other detect spells that might help you, especially detect magic, but those two are probably the best, and most accessible to your party.

Non-magical means include peering under the door or through a keyhole (looking for light, moving shadows, a draft), opening the door a crack and peeking through with Move Silently, searching the door for trap triggers, feeling the door for heat or cold, and smelling. Get creative.

EDIT: There's been some discussion about the underlying problem here being that the DM is ambushing the players and they need a way to fight back. It's possible that the DM is being a bad DM, but it's also possible that they're running a dungeon that rewards paranoia because of the way it's designed.

I ran the World's Largest Dungeon a few years ago and encountered this problem. Every time the party hit a door, the players cast Detect Evil, Detect Magic, checked for traps, listened, opened the door a crack, checked the ceilings, and on and on. It got pretty laborious, and no one liked it.

The solution we hit upon was to establish a standard operating procedure for opening doors. Whenever they approached the door, I would just assume they'd listened, checked for traps, and cast detect evil without them needing to tell me so, and I'd give them the information straight away. They had to specifically tell me when they were deviating from the procedure, such as when they were running from an enemy or wanted to try something different. It worked pretty well. I recommend it.

Comment: +1 Using detect magic or detect evil are good thoughts -- I had forgotten that they can both penetrate barriers.  (Detect thoughts would definitely be good for a different party, though not ours.)

Comment: The favored soul can cast detect magic as a 0-level spell -- is it a worse choice because most monsters won't register as magical?

Comment: I guess it depends what you're looking for. But yeah, if you're looking for monsters, you'll probably see a lot more with Detect Evil than with magic. If you're looking for items or magical traps or illusions, detect magic is your jam.

Comment: I would lead with mundane solutions and follow-up with magical ones; they're low-level and can't necessarily afford to drop a 1st level spell at every door.  Also I suggest mentioning Move Silently; if it's a new GM and a new party, "opening the door a crack" may not register on the Skill Check radar just yet.

Comment: As addition to this, you could always try opening the door, take a look inside, then close the door. Have your strongest party member then barricade the door while you buff up if needed.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs I like that ;-)  Simple yet effective

Comment: @tex what would be the skill checks involved with "opening the door a crack"?  I would think that would be a Spot and/or Listen check for the monster(s) and that Move Silently wouldn't help the party much if the door is naturally squeaky ;-)

Comment: @PurpleVermont Yes exactly, Move Silently to crack open a door vs. Listen hear it moving.  I'd add a massive bonus to the monsters' Listen checks if the door is very squeaky.  :]

Comment: I like the first suggestion: Try knocking, throw your DM for a loop. If there's no response, characters should loudly proclaim in whatever tongues they know that "what happened to this generation? Dwarves/Gnolls/Kobolds/etc these days are so rude. Why, back in my day..."

Comment: @PurpleVermont also, if the hinges are facing the player, they should have the opportunity to oil/grease them if they're concerned about the door being squeaky when they try to open it. Of course there's always possibility of the door making other noises (scraping against the floor, popping out of its frame if it's a bit swollen, having a bell hung on the other side, etc), but that's much more at DM discretion and for use in preventing the party from just safely buffing-then-bashing/blasting their way through every room.

Answer (score 3):

Magical means are exhausted pretty fast if you cast something at every door you encounter. However, normal perception is not restricted to sound. Maybe you can ask different questions when your DM describes a door the next time:

- Does it have a keyhole to peek through? Getting eyes on target is even better than hearing it.
- How does the room feel? Is it hot or cold?
- What materials are the door and the walls made of?
- Is there light coming out of the cracks? Is it static like a torch, or periodically like someone breathing fire once in a while?

If you encounter a fire-proof stone-door, with dog-like creatures that gets hot every time light is emitted from it, chances are it's a pack of hellhounds. Be creative in your questions and don't rely on the "Listen" skill check alone.

Comment: Also, scout can Search for tracks leading to the door. If they're specific enough, a Knowledge check can reveal more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use magic items (edited to clarify it was potions anyone can use without UMD):

- With *Gaseous Form* (750 gp) potion you can move through cracks in most doors (remember you're not invisible) and scout other places (stairwells, etc.)
- With *Invisibility* (300 gp) potion you can actually risk knocking (remembering about creatures with scent and other abilities)
- *Ring of X-Ray vision* is not cheap, but 25,000 gp should be in range for 6-8 level PCs
- If anyone can learn Use Magic Device, arcane scrolls will be an option too or a Wand of Detect Thoughts.

Can the psion use [*Clairvoyant Sense*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/clairvoyantSense.htm)?

Comment: your quoted prices seem to be double the scroll prices.  Also those are both Arcane spells.  I think UMD is cross-class for all of us -- definitely is for the Favored Soul, who has high Cha.

Comment: I clarified my answer to indicate the prices concern potions. For a cross-class UMD it's tougher on lower levels, although for exploration losing several standard actions before you manage to activate an item is not much of an issue.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a little pricey for us right now to spend that much cash checking out a single door, but possibly worth grabbing a few such items for occasional use.

Answer (score 1):

### Psions are masters of seeing things that they aren't supposed to see

Psions have a second level power called [Clairvoyant sense](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/clairvoyant-sense) that allows them to see behind an obvious location, such as behind a door or on the other side of a wall.

They also have a power of the same level called [Object Reading](http://therafim.wikidot.com/object-reading), which allows them to touch an object and receive a history of the things that have occured involving that object. If you target the door you can receive a history of anyone who has used said door.

If you aren't a Seer you can utilize the power [Control sound](http://therafim.wikidot.com/control-sound) to completely nullify any sound created when opening the door, which will allow you to surprise whatever may be on the other side of the door if they are unaware of your presence.

Answer (score 1):

What strategies might you — personally — follow in the real world to figure out what lies behind a closed door? Listen at it? Look through the keyhole? See if there are any cracks in it/under it/above it? Open it a crack and have a peep?

Try some of those before reaching for the spells and special abilities.

Comment: While what you’re getting at makes for a good answer, answering a question with questions, even rhetorical ones, looks snarky and unprofessional to me. It does not have the authoritative and educational tone that we strive for here; we are here to help others.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the problem is on the DM's side, not yours.  You said that you got some rather high results and it still wasn't good enough to let you find out what was behind the door.  That tells me that the DM is putting stuff behind the door that's impossible for you to discover, and that's a failure to balance the adventure properly as well as basically harping on something trivial; specifically, that you're expected to run a full diagnostic scan on every door that you come across lest what's behind it ambush and slaughter the entire party.

My solution?  Point this out to the DM and ask what the DC for the Listen/Spot checks he's calling for are, then see if they're even possible for the party to semi-consistently make.  F'rex, if for some reason all of his enemies are ninjas that can't be heard on anything less than a 40 and the best Listen check anyone in your party can manage is a 25, then that's a sign that the DM needs to stop using those ninjas and maybe go back to some kobolds with pots and pans for armor.